# Import of big sets to MySQL

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to import wikipedia access logs(http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/) into mysql for internal use.
Target: draw a day/url graph

Wikipedia file name contains day and hour and has following structure:
language url visits size_of_answer

My current DB structure:

```
Table urls:
url_id;url_string;language  
Indexes on everything

Table visits:  
visits_id;url_id;day_stamp;visits_count  
Indexes on everything

Table temp:  
visits_id;url_id;url_string;language;visits_count;day_stamp
```

MySQL engine:InnoDB

Current method:

1. I filter raw logs to get only interesting for me. filtered file contains ca 250k lines and has a structure of "temp" table.
2. importing this file into "temp" with LOAD DATA INFILE.
3. Set url_id in "temp" for existing urls(UPDATE... JOIN temp with urls on url_strings).
4. INSERT urls from "temp" to "urls" where temp.url_id=0
5. Set again url_id in "temp" for existing urls(UPDATE... JOIN temp with urls on url_strings).
6. Set visits_id in "temp" for existing visits lines(UPDATE... JOIN temp with visits on url_id).
7. Insert visits from "temp" where visits_id=0
8. Update visits from "temp" where visits_id!=0

All this takes up to 5 minutes to import.

Is here the way to do it faster? Another steps, another DB?

Comment: Are these incremental updates?

Comment: How many rows in this table?

Comment: each hourly update contains ca 250k lines, ca 10% are new urls. Table "urls" will have max 2kk rows. Table "visits" much biger because of day/url